# How can I have my composite primar key in a junction table using sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, composite-primary-key, junction-table

I have a composite primary key in my table Foo, and a single primary key in Bar. When I make a junction using the belongsToMany syntax, only one primary key component shows up in the junction table (the first one that is beeing defined). I was expecting to see FooId, FooDate , BarId and state.

I'm using MariaDb 10.4.21 and sequelize v6.12.1 if that matters.

```
  const Foo = sequelize.define("Foo", {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, unique: true, allowNull: false
    },
    date: {
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY, primaryKey: true, unique: true, allowNull: false
    },
  });

  const FooBar = sequelize.define("FooBar", {
    state: {  
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }
  });

  const Bar = sequelize.define("Bar", {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, unique: true, allowNull: false
    }
  });


  Foo.belongsToMany(Bar, { through: FooBar});
  Bar.belongsToMany(Foo, { through: FooBar});
```

I know I could do a workaround by just using a single primary key, but I want to understand my mistake. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize does not support composite primary and foreign keys so you need to make `id` in `Foo` as the only unique key (ideally should be generated by DB) and so you will have a one foreign key column in `FooBar` per each table.